# Как сделать подобный вырез блока?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как сделать вырез блока, как на фото?
И чтобы он при масштабировании оставался сохранным? 
Я пробовал обрезать в фотошопе и оставить белый фон на месте вырезанного, поместить фото в `background`, но при изменении страницы все летит и все фото срезается, а следовательно теряется треугольник.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: и еще сотни подобных

Comment: @StrangerintheQ там по ссылке нету реализации на векторной графике ...может сделаешь ?

Comment: @MaximLensky нет, я не буду

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/BEVPJY дальше делать лень - сами продолжите

Comment: @MaximLensky все получилось, спасибо, а как еще сделать круг со стрелкой? У меня обрезанные под треугольник края обрезают псевдоэлемент, который я указал

Comment: @QuickBrownFox абсолютным позиционированием ...обычный div с радиусом ...

Comment: @MaximLensky получается примерно вот что https://ibb.co/q76J3ZF

Comment: @MaximLensky подскажите, пожалуйста, как гуглить инфу, чтобы найти как овалдеть этим приемом, он кажется мне чем-то из разряда высшей математики пока что))

Comment: @QuickBrownFox я не видел такой инфы ...это всё приходит с годами

Comment: @QuickBrownFox Как и высшая математика, кстати если у Вас с ней сложности и Вас это не устраивет рекомендую https://betterexplained.com, там хоть и на английском, но все равно понятнее чем Вам рассказывали раньше.